# Log apache start and stop in log file

Tags: apache

Is it possible to log the start, stop and restart messages in a different log file?

I want to use the date and time of the specific message in PHP.

```
[Tue Jul 16 14:00:13.378138 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 376:tid 392] AH00455: Apache/2.4.34 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0i PHP/7.2.9 configured -- resuming normal operations

[Tue Jul 16 14:02:50.737738 2019] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 376:tid 392] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with apache conditional logs & multiple access logs.

**multiple access logs.**

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
CustomLog logs/access_log common
CustomLog logs/referer_log "%{Referer}i -> %U"
CustomLog logs/agent_log "%{User-agent}i"
```

**Conditional access logs.**

```
# Mark requests from the loop-back interface
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "127\.0\.0\.1" dontlog
# Mark requests for the robots.txt file
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/robots\.txt$" dontlog
# Log what remains
CustomLog logs/access_log common env=!dontlog
```

> Reference URL : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html